# How to replace menu dynamically with another in Android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a ListActivity (`SherlockListActivity`) and its content can be dynamically changed by the user. When the content changes, *the options menu should be replaced*.

As I [learned](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29), instead of  `onCreateOptionsMenu` I should use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` that is (supposed to be) called every time the user selects the menu.

> This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown.

I have the following code:

```
@Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
    menu.clear();
    if (UserOption == UserOption1)
      getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_option1, menu);
    else
      getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_option2, menu);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

It is called only once during debug, so I always have the same menu.

What should I set to make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7066901/3850595

Comment: use invalidateOptionsMenu() in where you want to refresh your menu

Comment: @JordiCastilla The main problem is that I have to use inflate to create a new layout and a simple reference to a menu does not help.

Comment: @ArunShankar Almost there, but the menu is replaced only after the _first interaction_ and not immediately.

Comment: @ArunShankar Using `invalidateOptionsMenu` is the solution. If you change your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Create and prepare the options menu for changing and its item selection method**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if(menuString=="red"){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.red_menu, menu);
        }else if(menuString=="green"){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.green_menu, menu);
        }
        return true;
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.new_game:
                return true;
            case R.id.help:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**Like whenever you want to change menu call**

```
String menuString="red or green";
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Like others told, if you want to have static menu use `onCreateOptionsMenu`, and if you want to change its visibility dynamically use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` along with `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: I have to inflate a new layout dinamically. Your solution does not cover that.

Comment: what layout, you mean listview..?

Comment: A new menu layout, every time.

Comment: check my updated answer, it will now clear the existing menu and inflate new one

Comment: I also suggest using `onPrepareOptionMenu` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: do you want to inflate menu, when clicking on menu items, if so onPrepareOptionMenu come in handy, otherwise  onCreateOptionsMenu is enough.