# Retrieve menu items from menu resources for custom view

Tags: java, android, menuitem

Hey I'm working on a custom view and I need to retrieve menu items from menu resources (e.g. menu.xml from res/menu)  but I didn't found any way to do that. How can I get users menu items from resources?

Comment: Which menu do you mean? Some code or images will help quite a bit to help you.

Comment: post edited and I don't think code is necessary for this question @Flummox

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066657/android-how-to-dynamically-change-menu-item-text-outside-of-onoptionsitemssele)

Comment: In that situation there is an object of menu he gets from `onCreateMenuOptions` and if I add a menu item to that it will shows in my action bar too. that's not what I want @LucaNicoletti

Comment: I think that's the proper way of retrieving the menu. What do you need to do? You can always use `setHasOptionMenu(false)` to not show the menu

Comment: but I have another menu items in my activity and I can't do that @LucaNicoletti