# Title definition is not working in Android MenuItem

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my menu in my Android app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_fruit"
        android:title="Apple" />

 </menu>
```

I want to change the text of the item "Apple" to "Orange" so I put this in my `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method in my activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem fruit = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_fruit);
    fruit.setTitle("Orange");
    return true;
}
```

This does not work. I also tried setting it from an outside method after the menu was declared in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
public Menu menu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}

public void changeFruitTitle(){
    MenuItem fruit = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_fruit);
    fruit.setTitle("Orange");
}
```

None of these methods are working, the menu item on my screen still says "Apple" no matter what. I even put a breakpoint in the code and it says the value of the `MenuItem`'s title is "Orange" but on the screen it still reads "Apple".

Am I not refreshing the screen correctly? I call these functions again with

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

But still it does not change the title.

Anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you calling invalidateOptionsMenu() before you change the value?

Comment: No, I'm changing the value before I call invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: Have a look at that solution [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066657/android-how-to-dynamically-change-menu-item-text-outside-of-onoptionsitemssele)