# How to change a title of popupmenu

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a problem with changing of `popupmenu` title.

My goal is that there is a join menu in `popupmenu` list.

After user join the app by using the `popupmenu` button , I want to change the "join" title to "User profile".

But I don't know how to change the title of `popupmenu`.

If there has a solution, let me know how to change.

Here is the code

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu6"
    android:title="join"/>
```

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_menu://popupbutton

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), v);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(popupClick);
    popup.show();   
  } 

  PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener popupClick = new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuitem) {

        switch (menuitem.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.menu6: // here is a code of join 
                break;
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153331/5156075

Comment: That was hard to understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this answer
[Change PopupMenu items' title programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153331/5156075)
.

First create a boolean variable

```
private boolean menu6;
```

Create a menu object to check which popup item is clicked

```
  Menu menuOpts = popup.getMenu();

  if (menu6) {
    menuOpts.getItem(1).setTitle("User profile");
 }
```

Modify `onMenuItemClick` to this

```
switch (menuitem.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.menu6: // here is a code of join 
   menu6 = true
   break;
 }
```