# How to set menu items text programatically in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to apply localization to all the menu items in the navigation drawer in xamarin android. Since we add the menu items in menu.xml file i am not able to apply localization to the text. Can anybody tell me how to set text for menu items programatically from activity file in xamarin android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066657/android-how-to-dynamically-change-menu-item-text-outside-of-onoptionsitemssele

Comment: Thanks a lot..it worked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to dynamically change menu item text outside of onOptionsItemsSelected or onCreateOptionsMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066657/android-how-to-dynamically-change-menu-item-text-outside-of-onoptionsitemssele)